# Change settings for system keychain is disabled

Tags: macos, mac, keychain

I want to make some changes in the keychain system but the option is disabled. I have already tried to make some changes in the iCloud settings, lock and unlock, and restart the mac.

Disabled option:

[image: disabled option]

I'm looking for always enable codesign because this alert is shown too many times:

[image: permission asked too many times]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.